# Why can I not install ncurses development package?

Tags: debian, ncurses, asterisk

I am trying to configure `Asterisk 12.3.2` on `Debian 6.0.9` but I am getting an error:

```
"configure: error: *** termcap support no found (on modern systems, this typically means the ncurses development package is missing)".
```

When I try to install it by:

```
apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

I get the message that package cannot be found.

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using? Have you tried looking through the available ncurses packages with `apt-cache search ncurses`?

Comment: If you have issues with compilation, it is highly recommended NOT build asterisk but use rpm(pre-builded) version.

Comment: Asterisk is available for Debian, including a wheezy packport. Is there some reason you are trying to build it from source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

libncurses-dev is what you want.

Additionally, you may be interested to know that you can install all the current prerequisites with [contrib/scripts/install_prereq](http://svnview.digium.com/svn/asterisk/branches/12/contrib/scripts/install_prereq). You pass it the install argument like: `contrib/scripts/install_prereq install` to install all dependent packages on your system.

Answer (score 2):

Acording to this blog post titled: [How to install Asterisk 1.8.4 on Debian 6.0.1](http://letitknow.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/how-to-install-asterisk-1-8-4-on-debian-6-0-1/) I think you want to install `ncurses-dev` and not `libncurses5-dev`. They're building an older version of Asterisk but thought this might be of help in your situation.

Also you can see all the ncurse packages like so:

```
$ apt-cache search ncurses | grep dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem on `Centos 7` while trying to install `Asterisk 13.4`.

I solved it by installing `libtermcap-devel`.

```
yum install libtermcap-devel
```

It will automatically resolve and install `ncurses-devel`.